# Core data objects are okay on applicationWillResignActive but have <fault> on applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: core-data, save

When using core data I'm finding an issue where I save X number of objects with [context save] and everything works fine until I close the app and open it again, thereupon all the same objects have "data: fault". I've tried saving the context on applicationWillResignActive just to make sure the stack has been saved but to no avail. When I check the objects during the app resigning active they are good but checking them on app becoming active shows the faults. Something I'm missing? I'm not sure how these core data objects are faulting on app exit.

Answer (score 0):

So faulting is a way for core data to save memory until you need the objects and found the answer where I least expected it:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html

"Fault handling is transparent—you do not have to execute a fetch to realize a fault. If at some stage a persistent property of a fault object is accessed, then Core Data automatically retrieves the data for the object and initializes the object (see NSManagedObject Class Reference for a list of methods that do not cause faults to fire). This process is commonly referred to as firing the fault. If you send the Department object a message to get, say, its name, then the fault fires—and in this situation Core Data executes a fetch for you to retrieve all the object's attributes.

Firing Faults
Core Data automatically fires faults when necessary (when a persistent property of a fault is accessed). However, firing faults individually can be inefficient, and there are better strategies for getting data from the persistent store (see “Batch Faulting and Pre-fetching with the SQLite Store”). For more about how to efficiently deal with faults and relationships, see “Fetching Managed Objects.”

When a fault is fired, Core Data does not go back to the store if the data is available in its cache. With a cache hit, converting a fault into a realized managed object is very fast—it is basically the same as normal instantiation of a managed object. If the data is not available in the cache, Core Data automatically executes a fetch for the fault object; this results in a round trip to the persistent store to fetch the data, and again the data is cached in memory.

The corollary of this point is that whether an object is a fault is not the same as whether its data has been retrieved from the store. Whether or not an object is a fault simply means whether or not a given managed object has all its attributes populated and is ready to use. If you need to determine whether an object is a fault, you can send it an isFault message without firing the fault. If isFault returns NO, then the data must be in memory. However, if isFault returns YES, it does not imply that the data is not in memory. The data may be in memory, or it may not, depending on many factors influencing caching.
"